# file_put_contents error while running the PyroCMS installer

Tags: php, pyrocms, file-put-contents

http://pyrocms.com/documentation/pyrocms/v3.1#installation/installing-pyrocms/running-the-installer

Getting this error

`"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("file_put_contents(app/default/assets/admin/theme.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory") in "theme::partials/metadata" at line 24."`

What I tried so far?

- changing the permission of `storage` and `bootstrap\chache` to `777`

 - `php artisan asset:clear`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the following directories writable by your web server:

storage
public/app
bootstrap/cache

In your case, its public/app that you have missed.